# Magento 2 - Area code not set when running script via command line CLI

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line

I have created module for exporting my product data to script outside of Magento2.

This is my Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Oktarin\Nabavanet\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

  protected $markup=1.03;
  protected $markup_extra=1.02;
  protected $price_limit=1500.00;
  protected $pricefile;
  protected $prices;
  protected $pdv=0.25;
  protected $base_url="https://domain.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/";
  protected $base_image_url="https://domain.com/pub/media/catalog/product";
  protected $shipping_cost=35.00;
  protected $cats;
  protected $appState;
/*
  public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,\Magento\Framework\App\State $state) {
    $this->appState = $state; 
    parent::__construct($context);
  }



  public function execute() {
    $originalArea = $this->state->getAreaCode();
    $this->appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
    //reset original code
    $this->appState->setAreaCode($originalArea);
  }
*/

  public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection;
    } // end of function getProductCollection


  public function makeXml(){
/*
*/
  //  $originalArea = $this->state->getAreaCode();


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $this->appState= $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $this->appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
               // ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => '%702638%'))
                ->load();
 $product=array();
    foreach ($collection as $product_data){
      if(!empty($product_data->getEntity_id())){


        //Load the product categories
        $categories1 = $product_data->getCategoryIds();
        //Select the last category in the list
        $categoryId = end($categories1);
        $categoryObject=\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category=$categoryObject->create('Oktarin\Nabavanet\Helper\CategoryTree');
        $categoryTreepath=$category->getTreeByCategoryId($categoryId);

        if(!empty($product_data->getspecial_price())){
            $price=$product_data->getspecial_price();
            $regular_price=$product_data->getprice();
         }
        else{
          $price=$product_data->getprice();
          $regular_price=false;
        }

        // Dostupnost proizvoda
          switch($product_data->getproduct_availability()){
              case "3929":
                // Po narudžbi
                $availability="Po narudžbi";
                break;
              case "3930":
                // Na stanju
                $availability="Raspoloživo";
                break;
              case "3931":
                // Zalihe pri kraju
                $availability="Raspoloživost potrebno provjeriti";
                break;      
            }

          $product[]=array(
            "internal_product_id" => $product_data->getEntity_id(),
            "sku" => $product_data->getsku(),
            "ean" => $product_data->getean(),
            "name" => $product_data->getName(),
            "url" => $this->base_url.$product_data->getEntity_id()."/s/".$product_data->geturl_key()."/",
            "availability" => $availability,
            "category" => $categoryTreepath,
            "image_url" => $this->base_image_url.$product_data->getimage(),
            "additional_image_url" => $this->base_image_url.$product_data->getsmall_image(),
            "description" => $product_data->getshort_description(),
            "shipping_cost" => $this->shipping_cost,
            "regular_price" => $regular_price,
            "brand" => $product_data->getbrand(),
            "part_number" => $product_data->getpart_number(),
            "warranty" => $product_data->getgarancija_proizvoda(),
            "price" => $price,
            "specialPrice" => $product_data->getspecial_price(),
            "tehnickaSpecifikacija" => $product_data->getdescription()
          );
        } // end of of entity_id isnt empty
      } // end of foreach 
        //reset original code
    $this->appState->setAreaCode($originalArea);
        return $product;
  } // end of function makeXml

} // end class
```

Method `makeXml()` I am calling from another script in file `nabavanet-export.php` that is designed to be run from cron/CLI/command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
(PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) && die('cli only');
require_once __DIR__ . "/include.php";

$nabavanet=new Xml();

  /* MAGENTO start */
  // calling on Magento Helpers
  use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
  require '../app/bootstrap.php';
  $params = $_SERVER;
  $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
  $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
  $nabava = $obj->get('\Oktarin\Nabavanet\Helper\Data');
  // end of Magento Helpers
  /* END Magento */

try{
  $filename="nabavaexport";
  $xml=$nabavanet->createNabavanetXMLfile($nabava->createXml(),$filename);
if($xml==1){
    echo "XML ".$filename.".xml generated!\n";
  copy($filename.".xml", "../nabavanet/".$filename.".xml");
}
else{
    echo "XML ".$filename.".xml not generated\n";
}


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // detaljan ispis grešaka slanjem
    // PDOException objekta preko varijable $e
    // PDO objekta preko varijable $db
    // PDOStatement objekta preko varijable $stmt
    showPDOErrors($e, $db_read, $stmt_read);
    showPDOErrors($e, $db_write, $stmt_write);
}           

?>
```

Script `nabavanet-export.php` was working fine when run through browser, however when I run it through command line I get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Area code is not set in /usr/www/users/shopyb/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:152
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/shopyb/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(173): Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode()
#1 /usr/www/users/shopyb/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start()
#2 /usr/www/users/shopyb/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(130): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start()
#3 /usr/www/users/shopyb/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\C in /usr/www/users/shopyb/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 175
```

As you can see I have tried implementing fix as said many times:

```
  public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\State $state, $name=null) {
    $this->appState = $state; 
    parent::__construct($name);
  }
```

But this also generated error

So I have tried modifing it like this but without success:

```
  public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,\Magento\Framework\App\State $state) {
    $this->appState = $state; 
    parent::__construct($context);
  }
```

I hope someone can give me pointers how to make file `nabavanet-export.php` run as command line.
I need that outside script because it is depending on other methods required for generating xml.

---

## UPDATE 1

Fix by Sukumar Gorai worked for me however new problem occured, I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: No such entity with id =  in /usr/www/users//vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:49
```

The script in Data.php should get product information, and it seems that it gets product without ID?

---

## UPDATE 2

The problem with `entity_id` was due to `false` value returned while fetching categroy ids in another class. I have managed to get around it :).

Thank you all for great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your script **nabavanet-export.php** like below:

```
<?php
(PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) && die('cli only');
require_once __DIR__ . "/include.php";

$nabavanet=new Xml();

/* MAGENTO start */
// calling on Magento Helpers
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
// Set area code
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$nabava = $obj->get('\Oktarin\Nabavanet\Helper\Data');
// end of Magento Helpers
/* END Magento */

try{
  $filename="nabavaexport";
  $xml=$nabavanet->createNabavanetXMLfile($nabava->createXml(),$filename);
if($xml==1){
    echo "XML ".$filename.".xml generated!\n";
  copy($filename.".xml", "../nabavanet/".$filename.".xml");
}
else{
    echo "XML ".$filename.".xml not generated\n";
}


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // detaljan ispis grešaka slanjem
    // PDOException objekta preko varijable $e
    // PDO objekta preko varijable $db
    // PDOStatement objekta preko varijable $stmt
    showPDOErrors($e, $db_read, $stmt_read);
    showPDOErrors($e, $db_write, $stmt_write);
}           

?>
```

Comment: I have tried and got this error `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor given, called in /usr/www/users//vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in /usr/www/users//vendor/magento/framework/App/Helper/AbstractHelper.php:84`

Comment: This error is in helper class of your. Please check the helper class properly and run the di compile again and then test.

Comment: it seems that it is working, after I ran setup:di:compile... however new problem occurs - please see "update" in original question

Comment: Great. Does the error has been fixed of areacode?

Comment: Yes - it seems that error has been fixed

Comment: Great. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

**Call AreaCode frontend inside module like this**

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State **/
private $state;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\State $state) {
    $this->state = $state;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function execute() {
    $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND); // or \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, depending on yexternals
}
```

**Call AreaCode frontend in externel script like this**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
```

Comment: do I need to call AreaCode in both locations: module and external script?

Comment: I have setup your code in both locations. Now I get this: `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper::__construct(), 0 passed in /usr/www/users/app/code/Oktarin/Nabavanet/Helper/Data.php on line 21 and exactly 1 expected in /usr/www/users/vendor/magento/framework/App/Helper/AbstractHelper.php:84`